# batch file doesn't echo into a file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, echo, yaml

why do these lines not work?

```
echo   POSITION-X: %shopxpos%>>shop%shopid%.yml
echo   POSITION-Y: %shopypos%>>shop%shopid%.yml
if "%shopincludedata%" == "y" (echo   DATA-VALUE: %shopitemdata%>>shop%shopid%.yml) else if "%shopincludedata%" == "Y" (echo   DATA-VALUE: %shopitemdata%>>shop%shopid%.yml) else if "%shopincludedata%" == "yes" (echo   DATA-VALUE: %shopitemdata%>>shop%shopid%.yml) else if "%shopincludedata%" == "YES" (echo   DATA-VALUE: %shopitemdata%>>shop%shopid%.yml) else if "%shopincludedata%" == "Yes" (echo   DATA-VALUE: %shopitemdata%>>shop%shopid%.yml)
```

they just don't spit out into the file
here's the file i'm using this in: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xui34kgkdjmee3p/ChestCommands.bat?dl=0

Comment: In order to debug your script, remove line 3 `@echo off` in your script. That should give you more insight in what is actually happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the values of %shopxpos% and %shopypos% are single digit numbers, and single digit numbers are used to identify which file handles should be redirected. You want the number to be treated as a literal string value to be ECHOed, but the parser is treating the number as a file handle identifier instead.

The simplest solution is to move the redirection to the front of the command. It can appear anywhere.

I would not check for all those variations of "yes". Instead, I would check to see if the first character is `Y`, case insensitive.

```
>>shop%shopid%.yml echo   POSITION-X: %shopxpos%
>>shop%shopid%.yml echo   POSITION-Y: %shopypos%
if /i "%shopincludedata:~0,1%" == "y" >>shop%shopid%.yml echo   DATA-VALUE: %shopitemdata%
```

or better yet, use parentheses and redirect only once.

```
>>shop%shopid%.yml (
  echo   POSITION-X: %shopxpos%
  echo   POSITION-Y: %shopypos%
  if /i "%shopincludedata:~0,1%" == "y" echo   DATA-VALUE: %shopitemdata%
)
```

Comment: how can i make it spit out not the %player% text, not a variable? used here: echo   COMMAND: 'eco give %player% %shoppricesell%'>>shop%shopid%.yml     it should be COMMAND: 'eco give %player% 5' but is COMMAND: 'eco give  5'

Comment: @David - Are you sure player is defined? If it was defined in the same parenthesized block where you attempt to print it, then you need to enable delayed expansion (`setlocal enableDelayedExpansion` at the top) and use `!player!` instead of `%player%`. If you want to echo the literal text `%player%`, then you need to double the percents.

Comment: yup figured out it needed %%player%% anyway here's the finished file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xui34kgkdjmee3p/ChestCommands.bat?dl=0